# How to validate user input in ASP.NET without using render blocking Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation, pagespeed, .net-4.5.2

Is there any way I can do form validation without having render blocking javascript?

Currently I am using a `ScriptManager` component with `RequiredFieldValiudator`, but when I test the site using Google PageSpeed it marks me down for:

> Your page has blocking script resources.
>   This causes a delay in rendering your page. None of the
>   above-the-fold content on your page could be rendered without waiting
>   for the following resources to load. Try to defer or asynchronously
>   load blocking resources, or inline the critical portions of those
>   resources directly in the HTML.
>
> ```
> Remove render-blocking JavaScript:
> http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.5.1/1/MicrosoftAjax.js
> http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.5.1/1/MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js
> http://www.time-attendance.co.uk/ScriptResource.axd?…B8XASQ-UWZeiQXFaROZWrCMBQEcF0mY63_ScGRI1
> ```

I have set the `LoadScriptsBeforeUI="False"` but PageSpeed is still not happy with it. Is there any way to satisfy the goolge requirement whilst still using asp.net components?

Comment: many alternatives such html5 and jquery plugin

Comment: Maybe Google expects you to load the scripts only when you need them, like [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) does.